# Suitable design pattern for business to persistence layers

Tags: mongodb, design-patterns, data-structures, architecture

I am using mongoDB that stores a simple product collection. I'm accessing this database from mongolab's API, so there is no direct access to the actual DB.

On the the other side, I have a Product model that has the same properties as the product document in the DB.

My question is: what design pattern(s) is(are) suitable in order to connect my business layer to the persistence layer.

So far I see these steps:

Product creation:

1. Create and populate the Product Model
2. Construct the endpoint URL for the API
3. Send request

Product retrieval:

1. Call methods like `getProductByName()` or `getProductByCode()`
2. Construct the endpoint URL for the API
3. Send request
4. Create and populate the Product Model based on the response.

I want to make the persistence layer as abstract as possible because in the future I might change the way I store and retrieve data. Also, this will be a simple application, so there is no need in using complicated logic or full ORMs.

Comment: One important thing I forgot to mention is that the processes above are happening inside an Android application as an asynchronous process so at one point, there should also be another layer that needs to create and manage different background processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not an Android developer but I think my answer might be helpful. If your persistence layer is really simple and you are just going to have several methods there, there's no reason to complicate it with overdesign. Here's what I would do if I were you:

1. Add a new project to the solution for DAL layer.
2. Create a contract/interface with all methods you need.
3. Add all DTO's you might need to serve as input or output parameters for the methods.
4. Create a repository class which implements the interface. make sure it deals with all the API stuff (constructing the endpoint, etc.)
5. Reference the newly created library in your business layer. Make sure you use IoC to instantiate it. It's important you always reference the interface not the class itself.
6. Add some mapping logic between your business layer stuff and persistence layer DTO's

Now if you want to store your data in a database directly or whatever, you will need to create one more class which implements the interface and replace the old one. The rest of your code will remain untouched. Btw, it will be easy to mock the persistence layer for unit tests then.

Hope it helps.